# New Mac OS - Texmaker - Help reference

Tags: bibtex

I used Texmaker for a while in Windows.
I just switch to Mac OS recently and everything is so annoying.

I currently have problem with reference. It does not work like it suppose in Windows.

1. I create a simple document `Testing article.tex`

   ```
   \documentclass[11]{article}
   \begin{document}
   This is testing document
   \cite{fama1993common}
   \bibliography{testref}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. I create a `testref.bib` with:

   ```
   @article{fama1993common,
     title={Common risk factors in the returns on stocks and bonds},
     author={Fama, Eugene F and French, Kenneth R},
     journal={Journal of financial economics},
     volume={33},
     number={1},
     pages={3--56},
     year={1993},
     publisher={Elsevier}
   }
   ```
3. Then I hit F1 in Testing article.tex to make PDF, but it keep showing:
   "This is testing document [?]"

This is two message I get when
- First, running F1
- Second, Tool -> BibteX

[image]
[image]

What should I do.
I search many, but they all guide in Mactex which I do not prefer to use
Thank you

Comment: You have to add an style like `\bibliographystyle{plain}` before `\bibliography{testref}`. Also change class option `11` to `11pt`.

Comment: Off-topic: The contents of the `journal` field should be `Journal of Financial Economics`, not `Journal of financial economics`. And, do use punctuation after truncated middle initials in the author field, i.e., please write the `author` field as `Fama, Eugene F. and French, Kenneth R.` rather than as `Fama, Eugene F and French, Kenneth R`. Why? Because the authors' actual middle names are `Francis` and `Ronald`, respectively, not just `F` and `R`. By providing the `.` punctuation marks, you avoid creating any uncertainty as to whether `F` is the actual middle name or an abbreviation.

Comment: note all the issues mentioned apply to any latex and bibtex version: there are no windows/mac differences here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are some main issues here:

1. You did not add an bibstyle command like `\bibliographystyle{plain}`
2. The used class option `11` is wrong. use `11pt` instead.
3. Be sure you follow the usual compiling chain: `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `bibtex mwe.aux`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`, `pdflatex mwe.tex`

Following this advices you get the following MWE `mwe.tex`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{testref.bib}
@article{fama1993common, 
  title={Common risk factors in the returns on stocks and bonds}, 
  author={Fama, Eugene F. and French, Kenneth R.}, 
  journal={{J}ournal of {F}inancial {E}conomics}, 
  volume={33}, 
  number={1}, 
  pages={3--56}, 
  year={1993}, 
  publisher={Elsevier}, 
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt]{article} % <=======================================
\begin{document} 
This is testing document 
\cite{fama1993common} 
\bibliographystyle{plain} % <===========================================
\bibliography{testref} 
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: bibliography]

Please see that package `filecontents` is only used to have `tex` code and `bib` file concatenated into one compilable MWE.

Comment: +1. Just don't use `\jobname.bib` for the code given on this site. Why? In the past, there have been cases of users who were already using `\jobname.bib` for their real, multi-entry bib files. After these guys (or maybe gals...) ran the well-intended example code that used `\jobname.bib` as well, they'd find that their real bib files had gotten clobbered. Moral of the story for folks providing answers -- use a name such as `mybib.bib` or `testbib.bib`. Much less scope for causing untold grief...

Comment: @Johannes_B -- An inexperienced LaTeX user might blindly run the MWE *as is*, with the `filecontents` package loaded. I seem to remember that it was @moewe who pointed out this issue to me, a couple of years ago. There really had been one or two cases of inexperienced LaTeX users managing to clobber their real bib files. Their main tex file was called, say, `project.tex`, and their bib file was called, you guessed it, `project.bib`. :-(